# Does missing schemas in MySQL matter?

Tags: mysql

[image]

Hey guys so i was following a tutorial and setting up my MySQL but I don’t know why I’m missing out the the ‘sys’.
I have the rest in my pc. Do i need to be worried? Or it doesn’t matter? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will break if you don't have the `sys` schema. It contains some views that are useful for some types of monitoring or debugging, but it's an add-on and it's not critical for MySQL functionality.

Are you using MySQL 5.6? The sys schema was an optional add-on in that version. In subsequent versions of MySQL (5.7, 8.0), the sys schema was created by default upon installation (though it is still possible to drop it). If you are using MariaDB instead of MySQL, then I'll leave it to you to look up which versions have the sys schema.

Comment: I'm using MySQL, not sure of the version, but i just got it installed today. When i first installed it i had the sys schema, but i accidentally deleted it. What can i do to get it back?

Comment: You can find out your version by running the `SELECT VERSION();` query in any MySQL client.

Comment: Some nice instructions for installing the sys schema if it is missing: https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/11/20/sys-schema-mysql-5-6-5-7/ Another site is the github project where sys schema originated: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys